# Filter: FMDatabase vs. NSDictionary vs. NSArray

Tags: ios, performance, sqlite, nsarray, nsdictionary

In my current application, I have a data table which holds a little more than 10,000 rows of data, each consisting of about 20 properties. Yes, this might seem odd, but there is no other way to hold the data.

Upon application start, all data is read into an NSDictionary. Each object is an instance of a custom class that holds the same properties as the database table. Pretty basic stuff.

In a UITableView, I want to display a filtered "subset" of this data. Regarding the performance on mobile devices, which way of filtering the data is the fastest or least memory consuming?

1. FMDatabase and SELECT-query, basic WHERE-syntaxx
2. NSArray, iterating over each object and temporarily storing matching ones in another NSArray (resp. NSMutableArray)
3. same as 2, but with NSDictionary objects

Thanks in advance for suggestions!

Comment: If all data is read into a dictionary, you can user NSPredicate to filter the data.

Comment: Least memory means not reading everything into the dictionary. If the data is already in an SQL DB then select out only the data you need.

Comment: Just noticed that I don't even need all 10k rows when the app is started. Just SELECTing the ones I need for the given filter would indeed be the best solution, why didn't it occur to me?! Thanks!